# Как можно вынести параметр представления view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли вынести параметр view так что б не создавать функцию?

Мне нужно выбрать "историю", т.е. выборка вида:

```
select * from filials p
  left join filials rea on rea.number = p.number 
  and (@date between         rea.dateopen and '12.12.9999')
where @date between p.datestart and p.datestop
```

Т.е. параметр `@date` в примере 2 раза (у меня раз 10) нитью пронизывает весь запрос, соответственно, это всетаки не функция, а выборка. Именно @date мешает просто вписать `create view as select` Можно ли как-то или в with параметр поставить... Можно ли эту выборку сделать именно view а не функцией? (Есть догадки что функция снизит быстродействие).

Мне нужно представление, т.е. `create view myview1 as ....` и параметр @date "мешает"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуй нужно оговорится, в [view](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) нельзя подставлять параметры. Но можно использовать другие возможности sql, ниже две из них:

1. Оказывается mssql позволяет задать "временный" параметр, который живёт внутри "сессии" запроса. Называется он [context_info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql). Предполагается что view используется один раз за одну выборку, при такой реализации.

   ```
   declare @v varbinary(8)
   set @v = cast(cast(floor( current_timestamp as float)) as bigint) as varbinary) --туда
   set context_info @v -- запомнили
   select * from my_viev
   ```

   ---

   ```
   create my_view as
   with CTE(date) as (
     select cast(cast(substring(context_info(),1,8) as bigint) as datetime) date -- назад
   )
   select * from filials p
    left join filials rea on rea.number = p.number 
    and (date between         rea.dateopen and '12.12.9999')
   where date between p.datestart and p.datestop
   ```

   Подзапрос использовал что б удобнее была выборка. В `context_info` можно засунуть много параметров. Конечно если две view затрагивают  context_info - будет конфликт.
2. Если известен список значений - можно преобразовать выборку так, что б она давала все варианты. Если вариантов не много (допустим 4-ре даты квартала за год), то можно преобразовать выражение так:

   ```
   create my_view as
   with CTE(date) as (
     select cast('01.01.2018' as datetime) date 
     union select  cast('01.04.2018' as datetime) 
      -- .... ещё значения
   )
   select * from filials p
    left join filials rea on rea.number = p.number 
    and (date between         rea.dateopen and '12.12.9999')
   where date between p.datestart and p.datestop
   ```

   Вынося поле date в значения выборки - можно потом его отфильтровать. Т.е. `select * from my_view where date = @date` Хорошо бы узнать как подсказать sql что б это поле "фильтровалось" в первую очередь... возможно кто-то подскажет. Но при большом выборе дат (я пробовал 365 дней) мне выборку ускорить не удалось.

Comment: С функцией всё-таки было бы понятнее. Если переживаете за быстродействие, то используйте встраиваемые табличные функции (т.н. _inline table-valued functions_) - те, которые `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT ... FROM ...)` (см. [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#b-creating-an-inline-table-valued-function), пример "Б").

Answer (score 0):

Ну скажем

```
select * 
from (select @date d from dual) d
join filials p on 1=1
left join filials rea on rea.number = p.number 
                     and d.d between rea.dateopen and '12.12.9999'
where d.d between p.datestart and p.datestop
```

Устроит?

Comment: дак вроде хотели избавиться от `@date` ?

Comment: @teran Ну совсем-то от параметра не избавиться - не ветром же его надует...

Comment: И если я спереди допишу `create view my_view as ` ваше выражение - sql это разве пропустит?

Comment: @nick_n_a Значит, я неверно понял вопрос. Тогда CREATE PROCEDURE... ну а насчёт скорости - попробуйте таки потестировать, может, опасения напрасны?

Comment: Почитайте https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64e834bc-c473-41dc-bb3c-6fd3bcfa0d57/views-vs-stored-procedures?forum=sqlgetstarted - вроде вполне себе вменяемый ответ от Chirag Shah (Microsoft).